# Since Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions is not compatible with .NET 7.0 how can I host my WebApplication on https?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-7.0

I recently updated my projects to .NET 7.0 and found out that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions` is not compatible with the newest .NET 7.0.

How can I now host my app on .NET 7.0 on HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have migrated from 2.x ASP.NET Core version at some point. As mentioned [in the migration guide from 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references):

> A large number of NuGet packages aren't produced for ASP.NET Core 3.0. Such package references should be removed from your project file.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions` being among the list of packages which were not produced anymore since 3.0. They should be part of the shared framework:

> Features of ASP.NET Core that were available through one of the packages listed above are available as part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework. The shared framework is the set of assemblies (.dll files) that are installed on the machine and includes a runtime component and a targeting pack.

And:

> Projects that target the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK implicitly reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework.

So basically you need to just set `<Project Sdk=` xml element to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` ([read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference)) and everything should be available.